# app token and secret key of a facebook app

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I displayed facebook feeds in a angularjs app, with the graph API.

I use the app token of my FB app (just for that) for perform it.

But i don't understand what is the difference between app access token (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and secret key of the app (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/).

What is safe to use in my JS app ? Because all of visitors can see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App access token and app secret you should never give out anywhere. App access token can be used to do any request as your app. App secret can be used to get an app access token so it is equally bad.